# Universal Price Format

Tags: php, algorithm, standards, w3c

Is there a way to convert any price format into universal value like what *UNIX* time format does? So that I can reuse them in another localization.

Maybe by defining a standard price number from a specific country as the base?

Comment: You're asking the question and answering it. Choose a currency as base currency, and whenever you need to show the equivalent price in another currency, do the conversion.

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?ItDepends

Comment: This may help. Take a look at ISO 4217, the international standard currency code, which has a three-letter code and a three-digit number for each currency.  Also, “With two exceptions, all currencies are based on the decimal system.”  (“Joe Celko’s Data Measurements and Standards in SQL”)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions all by the way, I am still looking for the proper way to achieve this. Maybe it is a bit wrong to compare currency with time.

Comment: I don't see a programming problem in this question.